# C++ error: expression cannot be used as a function (find_if)

Tags: c++, dictionary

The essence of the program: get a map, where the values are char from the passed string, and the key is the number of these values in the string

```
using namespace std;

map<char, int> is_merge(const string& s) {
    map<char, int> sCount {};
    for (auto lp : s) {
        if (find_if(sCount.begin(), sCount.end(), lp) != sCount.end()) {
            sCount[lp] += 1;
        } else {
            sCount.insert(make_pair(lp, 0));
        }
    }

    return sCount;
}

int main()
{
    string test = "aba";

    map <char, int> res = is_merge(test);

    for (auto lp : res) {
        cout << lp.first << ":" << lp.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But an error occurs in the console: /usr/include/c++/12/bits/predefined_ops.h:318:30: error: expression cannot be used as a function 318 | { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); } | ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

Comment: You want `std::find`, not `std::find_if`.  `find` takes a value to find, `find_if` takes a function to find a value.

Comment: How can this be done in my example?

Comment: please add an example of input and expected output. its not really clear what you wnat to count with the map

Comment: `find_if` -> `find`, it's not complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::find_if` takes a predicate not a value. Hence the error that `lp` is not a callable. To find a key in a map you should use `std::map::find` because it is `O(logn)` compared to `O(n)` for `std::find`/`std::find_if` (as a rule of thumb you can remember: If a container has a member function that does the same as a generic algorithm the member function is at least as effcient, often better).

However, there is not need to check if the key is present via `find`. The function can be this:

```
map<char, int> is_merge(const string& s) {
    map<char, int> sCount {};
    for (auto lp : s) {
         ++sCount[lp];
    }

    return sCount;
}
```

`std::map::operator[]` already does insert an element when none is found for the given key. You don't need to do that yourself.

PS: And if you do call `insert` then there is no need for `std::make_pair` : `sCount.insert({lp, 0});`. `std::make_pair` is for when you need to deduce the type of the pair from arguments to `std::make_pair`, but you don't need that here.

PPS: And if you do use `std::find` you need to consider that the element type of your map is `std::pair<const char, int>`, not `char`.

Comment: It looks like the map is supposed to store the number of collisions rather than the count, so this will be 1 too high. Honestly though it's easier to do this and subtract 1 when printing.

Comment: @Useles good catch. OP writes " the key is the number of these values in the string" which I interpret as counting frequencies, but their code isnt that. Not sure which one is wrong code or text

Comment: @Useless well... "the key is the number ..." cannot be right :/